# Hydration of alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: Two different alkenes]

In the image I've provided, I offer two alkenes. The first is in conjugation while the second isn't. Additionally, both of the C=C groups are symmetrical, in the sense that they both have one hydrogen at each carbon.

My question is: what would happen when you hydrate each of these (acid catalysed hydration) with heat? Markovnikov's rule doesn't help because both carbons of the double bonds have one H each.  Where does the H go and where does the OH go?

I'm also interested to know if the conjugation (first molecule) has a different result from this reaction?

Comment: These two examples are unrelated - compound structures only look similar.

Comment: @Mithoron I am aware they are two different molecules.  My question is which carbon of each alkene group gets the H and which gets the OH in acid catalysed hydration, since Markovnikov's rule is not a consideration.
I have offered the two molecules in case conjugation produces a different result (e.g. possibly one product is more favoured when conjugation is present).

Comment: Two is such cases tends to be one too much. Another thing is you should analyse a bit the nature of intermediate carbocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st compound when you add water the intermediate carbocation is formed at the carbon nearer to the benzene ring as benzene ring being an electron withdrawing group delocalises the positive charge. So automatically $OH$ group gets attached in that position. But do not do anything to the benzene ring as if you do so, it loses its aromaticity.

For the 2nd one there is a hydride shift from the carbon lying at the intrsection of the ring and chain to the double bond position which forms more stable carbocation intermediate as positive charge resides on 3° carbon. So rather the $OH$ gets bonded to the $C-1$.
The products are as follows
[image]